# Entity Framework passing reference to static class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Everyone knows this

```
using (var db = new DatabaseEntites())
{
    var row = db.SomeTable.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == 5)
}
```

I planned to create a static class with a static method like this

```
public static class SomeTableRepository
{
   public static class GetSomeTableRow(DatabaseEntities db, int id)
   {
        return db.SomeTable.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == 5);
   }
}
```

and the first code would then look like this

```
using (var db = new DatabaseEntites())
{
    var row = SomeTableRepository.GetSomeTableRow(db, id);
}
```

If this would be a web app...would that kind of programming be ok...or could that kind of programming cause some trouble?...or is this perfectly good code :)

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with this, but what's the point of creating the static class? It doesn't really seem to get you anywhere.

Comment: Also... that's not really what a repository is </nitpick>

Comment: Yeah I know its not repository...maybe query repository :)...I am plannig to have some more complex queries in such a class so I can used them often if I need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kirk said, I think the only gain is minor readability. However, if you add `this` in front of your first parameter and make this an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), then you might gain some readability for potential readers of your code:

**UPDATE**

I also noticed that `public static class GetSomeTableRow` would not compile. I changed it to be more generic and less confusing for future readers (`class` to `YourClassName`)

```
public static class SomeTableRepository
{
   public static YourClassName GetSomeTableRow(this DatabaseEntities db, int id)
   {
        return db.SomeTable.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == 5);
   }
}

...

database.GetSomeTableRow(id);
```

Furthermore, you could rename this to make it read more like what it actually is:

```
database.GetOneRowFromSomeTableById(id);
```

Yes, it is lengthy, but the only reason to abstract such a simple method as `SingleOrDefault` would be to make the code even readable at a glance. The `ById` part is debatable since the parameter is named `id` (and it makes it seem redundant), however that only shows up while coding with intellisense. You could leave it out (or take it down to just `By` without `Id`...but that leaves too much for each implementer IMO)

```
database.GetOneRowFromSomeTable(id);
```

Comment: @TheMentor I updated my answer btw, the public static class GetSomeTableRow would not work...I am assuming you put class just meaning ClassName?

Comment: Yeah...I made a mistake...I type code directly...ofcourse return statement returns class...

Answer (score 5):

The code is technically acceptable, but why would you do it?  It's creating an indirection without making the code substantively more concise.  Thus you make your code harder for most people to understand.  The benefit is your code is two characters shorter.  That doesn't seem like a win to me.

Myself, I would use the standard LINQ operators unless I'm genuinely adding some real value.

Comment: as I said...maybe for more complex queries that you need them more than once in diffrent areas of your project...

Comment: Then your example should be a more complex query.